# Upper bound on the partial sum of binomial probability

Tags: probability, inequality, binomial-coefficients

I am interested in seeing a proof for the inequality $\sum_{i=D+1}^N {N \choose i} \epsilon^i (1-\epsilon)^{N-i} \leq {N\choose D+1}\epsilon^{D+1}$.

Edit:

$\sum_{i=D+1}^N {N \choose i} \epsilon^i (1-\epsilon)^{N-i}= ϵ^{D+1} (1-ϵ)^{N-D-1} {N \choose D+1} 2F1(1,D+1-N;D+2;ϵ/(ϵ−1)) $

which I can see is starting to look more like the right hand side.

(Edit 2: Small typo fixed by changing $n$ to $N$ in the first expression.)

Comment: This is simple to prove if you know about the Gaussian hypergeometric function. The problem is that we do not know what you know and what you already tried. Edit your post, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote
$$S=\sum_{i=D+1}^N {N \choose i} \epsilon^i (1-\epsilon)^{N-i}$$
$$S= \binom{N}{D+1}\epsilon ^{D+1} (1-\epsilon )^{N-D-1} \,
   \, _2F_1\left(1,D-N+1;D+2;\frac{\epsilon }{\epsilon -1}\right)$$

Using $\epsilon=\frac{t}{t+1}$
$$S=\binom{N}{D+1}\,t^{D+1}  \,\, _2F_1(D+1,N+1;D+2;-t)$$

that is to say
$$S=\binom{N}{D+1}\,t^{D+1}\Bigg[1+\,\frac{D+1}{N!} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\, \frac{(N+n)!}{n! \,(D+1+n)}\,t^n\Bigg]$$
$$S <\binom{N}{D+1}\,t^{D+1}$$